# Sys.info() not displaying in dashboardbody box

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display the output of Sys.info() inside of a box(), but all it is displaying is one word "Darwin".

If I do `str(Sys.info())` I get

```
Named chr [1:8] "Darwin" "15.5.0" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "sysname" "release" "version" "nodename" ...
```

So how can I display this as a block of text in a box? Should it be called in the server code and displayed in a textOutput instead?

Here is the dashboardBody code block which is in `ui.R` it is in a shinyUI(dashboardPage(...)):

```
dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
        box(
            title = "Time and Date", 
            status = "primary", 
            solidHeader = TRUE, width = 4,
            "Time: ", Sys.time(), br(),
            "Date: ", Sys.Date(), br(),
            "Time Zone: ", Sys.timezone(), br(),
            Sys.info(), br()
        )
    )
)
```

server.R is just empty:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
```

Comment: You could construct the "Sys.info" string using `paste` to create the output you want (i.e. one string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see the warning?

> Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
>     argument should be a character vector of length 1
>   all but the first element will be ignored

Use this instead:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        box(textOutput("sys_info")),
        box(tableOutput("sys_info2"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


    output$sys_info <- renderText({
        a <- Sys.info()
        a
    })

    output$sys_info2 <- renderTable({
        a <- data.frame(Sys.info())
        a
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```